# How to control array state with vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to read state array by vuex.
But it says

> "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

I guess [0] happens error.
 
Here is some code below.

```
// the code of index.vue
<template>
  <div><p>{{ rectangles[0].x }}</p></div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    computed: {
            rectangles () {
                return this.$store.state.rectangles
            }
    },
  }
</script>
```

And this is the store of vuex.

```
export default {

  state: {
    rectangles: [
      {
        x: 150,
        y: 100,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        fill: "red",
        name: "rect1",
        draggable: true
      },
      {
        x: 150,
        y: 150,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        fill: "green",
        name: "rect2",
        draggable: true
      }
    ],
  },
```

Comment: Can you post your code somewhere like jsfiddle, codesandbox, etc?

Answer (score 1):

```
computed: {
            rectangles () {
                return this.$store.rectangles
            }
    },
```

Should be

```
computed: {
            rectangles () {
                return this.$store.state.rectangles
            }
    },
```

But the best way is using getters (link: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html )

Comment: Sorry. I edited that since that is an error. So the problem is same yet..

Comment: You can try close the tag `<div>` here at the end `<div><p>{{ rectangles[0].x }}</p>`

Comment: Are you using modules in your store?